# 2.3 Performance: Accurate Metadata for online store?

Tags: ios, flutter, app-store

I made an app with flutter and tried to upload it to app store but my app rejected, this is the message they send to me:

> Guideline 2.3.10 - Performance - Accurate Metadata
>   We noticed that your app or its metadata includes irrelevant third-party platform information.
>   Specifically, your app includes non-iOS device images in the app binary.
>   Referencing third-party platforms in your app or its metadata is not permitted on the App Store unless there is specific interactive functionality.
>   Next Steps
>   To resolve this issue, please remove all instances of this information from your app and its metadata, including the app description, promotional text, What's New info, previews, and screenshots.
>   Please see attached screenshots for details.

They give me screenshot from app with xiaomi phone on it, it's a product data that requested from a web service.

I created app for a store that sell various gadgets including iOS and Android, i knew there is another app that also have something similar like this but i don't know how it can pass app store either

Is there any suggestion i can try?

Screenshot they gave to me (i cropped it to focus on xiaomi device)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

check your description that you have to not added any irrelevant information.you need to update your description,make sure you don't write any specific device information on the description as their guideline.update the description so that it only gives what your app is actually doing and delete all the non essential part from it.And add your snapshot relevant (just add ios device screenshot),yours got rejected because it's showing redmi device without any specific reason(Specifically, your app includes non-iOS device images in the app binary).include screenshot with ios device and re submit and add note in the note section(at the bottom of the page ) that how your app works in detail.

Comment: thank you hemant, i will try to change my app description, also if i want to add a reason about showing redmi device where should i inform them?

Comment: you should write that in note section but if the image is only for representation purpose than i guess you can not show that as noted above.but maybe you can show some ios devices or show mix list of android and ios device in screenshot.